# Simple, easy to configure streaming server for linux - just transcode & stream

Tags: streaming, webvideos

After spending a few hours setting up and configuring PlexMediaServer, I realized that it looks *awesome* for home use, but has some impediments for serving up content to the public at large.

I have 50 or so video presentations (genetics & infant healthcare if you must know) that need to be served up.  The presentations will be available on a web page, and I would simply need a link to point back to a file that the streaming server would transcode & play.  The HTML is not important - I can have simple href links for that.

Are there any relatively easy to configure and set up streaming servers that can offer this basic functionality?   My server is CentOS 6.5.

Comment: Why does it need to be streamed? It isn't clear from the question that static content wouldn't work. Why do you want transcoding to be part of the streaming, rather than part of the publishing phase? I'm sure you have reasons.

Comment: Because a streamed video can be played inline, with additional styling & features on the page itself.  I lose that when users download and play with a client.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense for why you want a streaming solution. How about the transcoding?

Comment: I think I found a workable solution in `ViMP`.  Installed & configured today and it seems to do just what I need.

Comment: OK, answer your own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with [ViMP Community Edition](http://www.vimp.com/en/web/vimp-community.html).  Took a little while to work through some dependencies but now that it is installed everything works exactly like I want.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-stream-videos-with-nginx-and-jwplayer-on-centos-6 makes Nginx look pretty simple to set-up as the streaming server. I've not used it but I have used jwplayer and that worked well for me (I was streaming from vlc/vlm). Another good option for the player end would be jplayer.

[Web Videos via Watch Folders Transcode](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7129) is a reasonable approach to the transcode issue.